# Compile all .c files in a directory using GCC compiler in CMD

Tags: gcc, compilation, cmd

Is there a way to compile all `.c` files in a given folder by using the command line with GCC compiler ?
I've seen this page for Linux : http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3230/compile-all-c-files-in-a-directory but couldn't find any equivalent for CMD.

Comment: I guess, there isn't a way, as mostly this wouldn't make sense for the linker. If you have project with multiple source files, you just should use a make file or write a build script which is also easyer to maintain.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I guess gcc itself doesn't have such a parameter.

But you can try the regular wildcard argument of `gcc *.c -o Output` where the `*` (wildcard) is to read as "any".

Comment: Use of `*` is known as [globbing](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html).

Answer (score -7):

You can compile your files with following command:

```
gcc -c -Wall file1.c file2.c file3.c
```

Here. -Wall will give you all the warnings and errors.

Do not forget to browse to the same directory where these files reside.

Comment: OP asked about compiling all files without writing them one by one