# How to Cygwin compile all .c files in a directory (globbing in Windows)

Tags: windows, gcc, compilation, cygwin, glob

#### Context

As the title suggest, I am trying to compile all `.c` files in a specific directory.

I am aware from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765536) that in Linux environment, you can use *globbing* and do `gcc -o executable *.c`. However, I am trying to do exactly the same, on a Windows environment.

#### Question

How can I compile all `.c` files in a specific/current directory using *Cygwin's* `gcc` command on a Windows 10 environment.

#### Additional Notes

- **Operating System:** Windows 10 (x64)
- **Runtime Environment:** Cygwin

---

#### Edit #1

Per [@matzeri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5105383)'s suggestion, I found out that globbing (`*.c` via the *Cygwin termninal*) works, however, I need to be able to do it via the terminal.

Comment: have you tried the same from the cygwin terminal ? Any problem ?

Comment: @matzeri using the cygwin terminal works. However, for convinience (and for VS code setting) I would need to be able to perform it through the Window's terminal.

Comment: If you plan to use the Cygwin compiler it is easier to use the Cygwin terminal and shell. If you are planning to compile a lot of different files, probably is better to learn and use `Make`

Comment: @matzeri good suggestion. For now, I am using `make`, though I wonder if there is a solution for my original question which is _globbing .c files via window's terminal_.